# Unable to connect to cloud shell from GCP console

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I've been running into the following error for a while now when trying to connect to my Cloud Shell instance from the console:

`Cloud Shell is experiencing some issues provisioning a VM to you. Please try again in a few minutes.`

I get the following error when I try to SSH into the Cloud Shell from the CLI:

```
$gcloud cloud-shell ssh
Automatic authentication with GCP CLI tools in Cloud Shell is disabled. To enable, please rerun command with `--authorize-session` flag.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The PuTTY PPK SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Pushing your public key to Cloud Shell...done.
Starting your Cloud Shell machine...
ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.ssh) HttpError accessing <https://cloudshell.googleapis.com/v1/users/me/environments/default:start?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Wed, 07 Dec 2022 11:22:20 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 503}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
>
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

Any thoughts on how i could resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the service account you are using. Use the default service account provided by the app engine.